# Combine records into one?

Tags: sql-server

```
CATEGORY     DESC                                       AMOUNT   
50200105 Sub Contractor - SLW                             1000     
50200205 Sub Contractor - Meal Operator - SLW             0   
50200305 Sub Contractor - Garbage - SLW                 2000
```

Result

```
CATEGORY                  DESC                            AMOUNT   
50200105                Sub Contractor - SLW              3000
```

Comment: please include the expected result in text and also show your current attempt.Also include the logic / explanation on the `combine` process

Comment: How you get only 50200105  where there are 2 other Category?

Comment: @mkRabbani I'm guessing there's a hidden parent-child relationship here with the `01`, `02`, `03` portions of the category code that OP hasn't explained to us.

Comment: how to sum combine 3 category to 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets achieve you output somehow with so many let ;)

let - you are trying to group by results with the last part of value in your column - DESCRIPTION.

Let - you are ok with keeping the MIN value from the CATEGORY column among the group.

Now- try this below query. Just trying to help you somehow :)

```
SELECT MIN(CATEGORY) CATEGORY, 
'Sub Contractor - '+ TRIM(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(DESCRIPTION), CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(DESCRIPTION),0)-1))) DESCRIPTION,
SUM(AMOUNT) AMOUNT
FROM your_table
GROUP BY TRIM(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(DESCRIPTION), CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(DESCRIPTION),0)-1)))
```

[Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a896ad023840f88ba7fdf25d5012aeca)

Comment: @FringgaAdamSandika seems it helps and nice to hear that. Please don't forget to put an up vote as well :)